# How to schedule millions of jobs in a node js properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

I am using `NodeJS`,`MongoDB` and `node-cron` npm module to schedule jobs. For 10K of jobs it is taking less time and less memory. But when i am scheduling 100k jobs it is taking more than 10 minutes to schedule jobs and taking nearly 1.5GB of RAM and some times out of memory. Is there any best way achieve this like using activemq or rabbitmq?

Comment: We're not all from India, so please avoid using Indian abbreviations & words here, like "L".

Comment: It heavily depends on your scheduling strategy. For example, if you're doing SJF then you can partition your db in a series of tables, and only load jobs that require between X and Y seconds when the table of jobs that require less than X seconds is empty...or if you're doing RR then you know in advance what's next, and the answer by @jfriend00 is useful for that

Comment: @malarres - If they are currently using node-cron successfully, then it appears they're doing time-based scheduling, not something like SJF.

Comment: @JamesZ, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is that you only schedule the next job to run. When it runs, you query the database and find the next job and schedule it.

If you add a new job, you check if it wants to run sooner than the now current next job and, if so, you schedule it and deschedule the previous next job (it will get rescheduled later after this new job runs).

If you remove a job, you check if it is the current next job.  If it is, you deschedule it and find the next job in the database and schedule it.

If your database is configured for efficiently querying by job run time, this can be very efficient, uses hardly any memory and scales to an infinitely large number of jobs.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. your strategy is absolutely works for me . I will try to implement it

Comment: @anil - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.